# trying to provision aws.yml provider playbook to setup my app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm not very experienced in aws nor ansible, but I've been trying to host and deploy a ready made medium size application to aws. I've already configured my profile with aws-cli, installed the pip modules and installed `amazon.aws` and `community.aws` collections using `ansible-galaxy`. however, when I run this command in order to provision the AWS provider playbook to set up my app by running this  `ansible-playbook -i inventory/forem/setup.yml playbooks/providers/aws.yml`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'amazon.aws.ec2'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/exodusreed/Desktop/wearerails2/selfhost/playbooks/providers/aws.yml': line 170, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: 'Launch Forem instance for {{ app_domain }}'
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

setup.yml

```
all:
  hosts:
  vars:
    ssh_key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/forem.pub') }}"
    app_protocol: https://
    database_pool_size: 10
    force_ssl_in_rails: 'true'
    lang: en_US.UTF-8
    node_env: '{{ forem_environment }}'
    rack_env: '{{ forem_environment }}'
    rack_timeout_service_timeout: 300
    rack_timeout_wait_timeout: 300
    rails_env: '{{ forem_environment }}'
    rails_log_to_stdout: 'true'
    rails_serve_static_files: enabled
    redis_sessions_url: redis://localhost:6379
    redis_sidekiq_url: redis://localhost:6379
    redis_url: redis://localhost:6379
    session_expiry_seconds: 1209600
    web_concurrency: 2
    forem_context: selfhost
    forem_container_tag: quay.io/forem/forem:latest
  children:
    forems:
      hosts:
        forem:
          ansible_connection: local
          ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3 # on macOS, this may need to be /usr/local/bin/python3
          # CHANGE_REQUIRED — forem_domain_name: example.com
          forem_domain_name: example.com
          # CHANGE_REQUIRED — default_email: your_email@example.com
          default_email: example@gmail.com
          forem_subdomain_name: www # can be subdomain, i.e. "community" in community.mainwebsite.com
          forem_server_hostname: host # You may change to something else if you choose (i.e. server, srv, etc)

          # CHANGE_OPTIONAL - strict-origin-when-cross-origin enables embedded youtube video playback
          referrer_policy: 'same-origin'
          # referrer_policy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
          app_domain: '{{ forem_subdomain_name }}.{{ forem_domain_name }}'
          secret_key_base: '{{ vault_secret_key_base }}'
          session_key: _FOREMSELFHOST_Session
          imgproxy_key: '{{ vault_imgproxy_key }}'
          imgproxy_salt: '{{ vault_imgproxy_salt }}'
          forem_version: latest
          forem_environment: production
          dd_api_key: '{{ vault_dd_api_key }}'
          honeybadger_api_key: '{{ vault_honeybadger_api_key }}'
          honeybadger_js_api_key: '{{ vault_honeybadger_js_api_key }}'
          honeycomb_api_key: '{{ vault_honeycomb_api_key }}'
          postgres_user: forem_production
          postgres_password: '{{ vault_forem_postgres_password }}'
          postgres_host: localhost
          pusher_app_id: '{{ vault_pusher_app_id }}'
          pusher_beams_id: '{{ vault_pusher_beams_id }}'
          pusher_beams_key: '{{ vault_pusher_beams_key }}'
          pusher_cluster: us2
          pusher_key: '{{ vault_pusher_key }}'
          pusher_secret: '{{ vault_pusher_secret }}'
          recaptcha_secret: '{{ vault_recaptcha_secret }}'
          recaptcha_site: '{{ vault_recaptcha_site }}'
          sendgrid_api_key: '{{ vault_sendgrid_api_key }}'
          sendgrid_api_key_id: '{{ vault_sendgrid_api_key_id }}'
          slack_channel: '#forem-activity'
          slack_webhook_url: '{{ vault_slack_webhook_url }}'

          # Required Ansible Vault secret variables
          # Use the following example commands below in a terminal to generate the required variables with Ansible Vault encrypt_string
          # These commands should be run in the selfhost directory, since the
          # ansible.cfg identifies the vault password which will be used to decrypt
          # if ansible-vault prompts for a password, something is not right
          # See this URL to learn more about ansible-vault:
          # https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#encrypting-individual-variables-with-ansible-vault

          # echo -n $(pwgen -1 128)|ansible-vault encrypt_string --stdin-name vault_secret_key_base
          # This is an example of an encrypted vault_secret_key_base variable looks like
          # vault_secret_key_base: !vault |
          #   $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          #   31626639326433353437623836636431303161363438396661636130646434396430633032343264
          #   3433343031316634636133636663666130303330636366350a616333366666656633353136363865
          #   32333739623836623362343862623963333834656236333433333665666531373534316238633039
          #   3136396237363839350a633764313365343033623061316364646135356336373062313433383866
          #   62613738336463366639323230626465353630646161323931396333333764633633303532656632
          #   33653839363465313863303533613062666364363563353264613439306539366665383462663234
          #   62313161333566373962396561376166333766366233396533356539393738623666656635373436
          #   36323064393461393836626537366239363433393261383137366664343734663161323162613634
          #   35353863356462326435656435373261386230356631396464653937643463323536656538313036
          #   346661356161386132643837386161376337

          # echo -n $(xxd -g 2 -l 64 -p /dev/random | tr -d '\n') |  ansible-vault encrypt_string --stdin-name vault_imgproxy_key
          # This is an example of an encrypted vault_imgproxy_key variable looks like
          # vault_imgproxy_key: !vault |
          #   $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          #   35646264656466303662316162353030343266366562633733623133326663656430356138306266
          #   6564343661366430383637633433343364363538316633340a336436653162363032646430333861
          #   33643061636336613361373430396332663964333230626661336637623336666366623839323564
          #   6432363731363339360a383361323863343131323837636633643261383034316534663634613835
          #   32316565343937306536343232313530383935386231333830343339653838303533383037616333
          #   33613732366236653466373233366234646437353166326164313764626439393165333861653538
          #   61343135373966303931656633363331313838653039626264396136623438626261356632356463
          #   64643666613930383938373337363238373032323166333730653734353463656139623838313939
          #   34626539626339353263376231623731656362636666636435366531346232363836613739386464
          #   303435353334366338646161333636643062

          # echo -n $(xxd -g 2 -l 64 -p /dev/random | tr -d '\n') |  ansible-vault encrypt_string --stdin-name vault_imgproxy_salt
          # This is an example of an encrypted vault_imgproxy_salt variable looks like
          # vault_imgproxy_salt: !vault |
          #   $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          #   32353437333561633733306239333164363165386437313632373761663535373661633261343833
          #   3534303539333235643530613530323964373530353437330a656636626432336633636132616430
          #   62316331396436626662303134343964366635316435653264386437653238643964363935643637
          #   3433623566346265640a343539303166333439626136343336643232643930393261313035313933
          #   36353833376139306266623261623561373235633432333462323230623665633562333565323235
          #   36366338646134633738323661656530663261336430633235643938383236353832626138356434
          #   30663337353235303038336239343934383065613532343137313038643330346436306261666130
          #   34323137633531393665343564613131343431373835336436656239313738303033333065623964
          #   30643262313833396234623937616632623561656664393739663266313531366332623434336565
          #   316634303133623165643138643831373630

          # echo -n $(pwgen -1 128)|ansible-vault encrypt_string --stdin-name vault_forem_postgres_password
          # This is an example of an encrypted vault_forem_postgres_password variable looks like
          # vault_forem_postgres_password: !vault |
          #   $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          #   32316238646635623832303464343262313831326131376662653037633265316166653439346163
          #   6231366436316431303164323634663137663866303036390a323736346236633835613962613634
          #   64616233353663643832636435396461393962616264623866613031633931396464346238646564
          #   3030336139303735640a646133313066383535643763353938663865363361356463623162366234
          #   37656661613334376361353331343437636633646331366466646130383731613939616639313638
          #   66613131333735383763656335393762346464346234626633313138376439633965363030616337
          #   65643663306266623764643732376535336339383334363131636537376531613738653764343865
          #   39316264633764383264396530393532333639643062333838373531626263623965366462633534
          #   33343834346333393737353432303065386433303065336563393634393065303838313162653035
          #   32306565616362346466643366356463656639333162343030323338656532613132303164373134
          #   343463383266383361303634356133326431

          # Optional Ansible Vault variables
          # echo -n foobarbaz |  ansible-vault encrypt_string --stdin-name vault_my_cool_vaulted_var
          vault_cloudinary_api_key:
          vault_cloudinary_api_secret:
          vault_dd_api_key:
          vault_honeybadger_api_key:
          vault_honeybadger_js_api_key:
          vault_honeycomb_api_key:
          vault_pusher_app_id:
          vault_pusher_beams_id:
          vault_pusher_beams_key:
          vault_pusher_key:
          vault_pusher_secret:
          vault_recaptcha_secret:
          vault_recaptcha_site:
          vault_sendgrid_api_key:
          vault_sendgrid_api_key_id:
          vault_slack_webhook_url:
```

aws.yml

```
---
- name: Deploy Forem to AWS
  hosts: all
  become: false

  collections:
    - amazon.aws
    - community.aws
    - community.general

  vars:
    fcos_arch: x86_64
    fcos_platform: aws
    fcos_format: vmdk.xz
    fcos_stream: stable
    fcos_aws_region: us-east-1
    fcos_aws_size: t3a.small
    fcos_aws_ebs_size: 100
    fcos_aws_profile: forem-selfhost
    butane_cleanup: true
    ssh_key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"

  roles:
    - preflight

  tasks:
    - name: Get FCOS facts
      include_role:
        name: fcos
        tasks_from: facts

    - name: Convert butane file to an Ignition file
      include_role:
        name: butane
        tasks_from: butane
      vars:
        butane_input_template: '../templates/forem.yml.j2'
        butane_aws_s3: true
        butane_aws_s3_url: "https://forem-selfhost-{{ app_domain |replace('.', '-') }}-ign.s3.{{ fcos_aws_region }}.amazonaws.com/forem.ign"

    - amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_net_info:
        filters:
          'isDefault': 'true'
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
      register: forem_vpc_info

    - name: Set forem_vpc_id fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        forem_vpc_id: "{{ forem_vpc_info['vpcs'][0]['vpc_id'] }}"

    - name: Gather info about VPC subnets
      amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_subnet_info:
        filters:
          vpc-id: '{{ forem_vpc_id }}'
          availability-zone: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}a'
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
      register: forem_subnet_info

    - name: Gather info about VPC AZs
      amazon.aws.aws_az_info:
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
      register: forem_az_info

    - name: 'Get route table facts for {{ forem_vpc_id }}'
      community.aws.ec2_vpc_route_table_info:
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        filters:
          vpc-id: '{{ forem_vpc_id }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
      register: forem_vpc_route_table

    - name: 'Generate list of route tables for {{ forem_vpc_id }}'
      set_fact:
        forem_vpcd_route_table_ids: "{{ forem_vpc_route_table.route_tables|map(attribute='id')|list }}"

    - name: 'Create S3 VPC endpoint in {{ forem_vpc_id }}'
      community.aws.ec2_vpc_endpoint:
        state: present
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        vpc_id: '{{ forem_vpc_id }}'
        service: 'com.amazonaws.{{ fcos_aws_region }}.s3'
        route_table_ids: '{{ forem_vpcd_route_table_ids }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
      register: forem_vpc_s3_endpoint

    - name: Set forem_vpc_s3_endpoint_id fact
      set_fact:
        forem_vpc_s3_endpoint_id: '{{ forem_vpc_s3_endpoint.result.vpc_endpoint_id }}'

    - name: Wait for S3 VPC Endpoint
      pause:
        seconds: 30

    - name: Create FCOS ignition bucket
      amazon.aws.s3_bucket:
        name: "forem-selfhost-{{ app_domain |replace('.', '-') }}-ign"
        state: present
        encryption: 'AES256'
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
        policy: |
          {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Id": "VPCEaccesstoignitionbucket",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Sid": "VPCE-access-to-ign-bucket",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::forem-selfhost-{{ app_domain |replace(".", "-") }}-ign/*"],
                "Condition": {
                  "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "{{ forem_vpc_s3_endpoint_id }}"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }

    - name: "Upload butane_ignition_stdout to forem-selfhost-{{ app_domain |replace('.', '-') }}-ign"
      amazon.aws.aws_s3:
        bucket: "forem-selfhost-{{ app_domain |replace('.', '-') }}-ign"
        object: '/forem.ign'
        content: '{{ butane_ignition_stdout | to_json | string }}'
        mode: put
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
      register: forem_ign_s3

    - name: Create Forem SSH key
      amazon.aws.ec2_key:
        name: 'forem-{{ app_domain }}'
        key_material: '{{ ssh_key }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'

    - name: 'Create Forem security group for {{ app_domain }}'
      amazon.aws.ec2_group:
        name: 'forem-{{ app_domain }}'
        description: 'Forem security group for {{ app_domain }}'
        vpc_id: '{{ forem_vpc_id }}'
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
        tags:
          'Name': 'forem-{{ app_domain }}'
        rules:
          - proto: tcp
            ports:
              - 22
            cidr_ip: '{{ local_wan_ip_address }}/32'
            rule_desc: 'Allow SSH access from {{ local_wan_ip_address }}'
          - proto: tcp
            ports:
              - 80
              - 443
            rule_desc: 'Allow HTTP and HTTPS access from 0.0.0.0/0'
            cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
        rules_egress:
          - proto: 'all'
            from_port: 0
            to_port: 65535
            cidr_ip: '0.0.0.0/0'
            rule_desc: 'Allow outbound access to 0.0.0.0/0'
      register: forem_security_group

    - name: 'Launch Forem instance for {{ app_domain }}'
      amazon.aws.ec2:
        key_name: 'forem-{{ app_domain }}'
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'
        group: 'forem-{{ app_domain }}'
        instance_type: '{{ fcos_aws_size }}'
        image: '{{ fcos_aws_image }}'
        wait: yes
        wait_timeout: 500
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ forem_subnet_info.subnets | map(attribute='id') | list | first }}"
        volumes:
          - device_name: /dev/xvda
            volume_type: gp2
            volume_size: '{{ fcos_aws_ebs_size }}'
            encrypted: yes
            delete_on_termination: no
        monitoring: yes
        assign_public_ip: yes
        user_data: '{{ butane_boot_ignition_stdout | to_json | string }}'
        instance_tags:
          App: 'forem'
          Domain: '{{ app_domain }}'
          Name: 'forem-{{ app_domain }}'
        count_tag:
          App: 'forem'
          Domain: '{{ app_domain }}'
          Name: 'forem-{{ app_domain }}'
        exact_count: 1
      register: forem_ec2_instance

    - name: Wait 300 seconds for port 22 to become open
      wait_for:
        port: 22
        host: "{{ forem_ec2_instance.tagged_instances | map(attribute='public_ip') | list | first }}"
        delay: 10
      connection: local

    - name: "Delete object forem-selfhost-{{ app_domain |replace('.', '-') }}-ign/forem.ign from S3"
      amazon.aws.aws_s3:
        bucket: "forem-selfhost-{{ app_domain |replace('.', '-') }}-ign"
        object: '/forem.ign'
        mode: delobj
        region: '{{ fcos_aws_region }}'
        profile: '{{ fcos_aws_profile }}'

    - name: Output EC2 setup message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - "The public IPv4 IP Address for {{ app_domain }} is {{ forem_ec2_instance.tagged_instances | map(attribute='public_ip') | list | first }}"
          - "Please add an A entry for {{ app_domain }} that points to {{ forem_ec2_instance.tagged_instances | map(attribute='public_ip') | list | first }}"
          - 'Example:'
          - "    {{ app_domain }} IN A {{ forem_ec2_instance.tagged_instances | map(attribute='public_ip') | list | first }}"
          - 'Once you have DNS resolving to this EC2 instance please read the Forem Admin Docs: https://admin.forem.com/'
```

note: the keys and secrets in `setup.yml` are properly configured and indented locally, they've been removed in the context of this question for security reasons.

any help or guidance to overpass this error are highly appreciated... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [amazon.aws.ec2_instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_instance_module.html) instead of `amazon.aws.ec2`